# Cannot Copy After Splitting Image into Channels in OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv, image-processing

I am attempting to split an image across its RGB channels and place them onto a canvas three times the width of the original image so I can place the split RGB channels side-by-side. Putting the original image onto this canvas works as expected but when I try to place the channels onto the canvas it does not work. When opening the region of interest I am attempting to place the channel onto it displays the copied channel but does not do the same for the canvas object.

I use the split() command to split the image into its channels where I store them in a vector. I have attempted to store them in an array with the same result. I use the Rect() command to get a region of interest. I have copied images into that region of interest so I know I am using it correct and it is the correct size. I use the copyTo() command which, as stated, works with other images but not the split channels.

Effectively, what I have is the following:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    Mat img = imread("img.jpg");
    vector<Mat> channelsRGB;
    split(img, channelsRGB);
    Mat channelsCanvas = Mat(img.rows*2, img.cols*3, CV_8UC3);
    Mat BChannel = channelsCanvas(Rect(0, 0, channelsRGB[0].cols, 
    channelsRGB[0].rows)); 
    channelsRGB[0].copyTo(BChannel);
    imshow("Canvas", channelsCanvas);
    waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Specifically instead of describing your code you'll need to provide a [mre].

Comment: Hey there, thanks for the tip. I've just now added some code so hopefully my problem and the solution becomes a bit more clear.

Comment: The code you have posted is working fine. You are not using `channelsRGB` (except for `cols` and `rows` of `channelsRGB[0]`). It is recommended to initialize `channelsCanvas` with zeros: `channelsCanvas.setTo(0);`. Why are you saying it's not working? Are you getting an error message? Please post a code sample that reproduces the issue, and describe the reason you are saying it's not working.

Comment: Why not just [`hconcat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga4676b1376cdc4e528dab6bd9edc51c1a) after the split? | "it does not work" -- what exactly does that mean? | Affter split, you're left with 3 single channel images. Yet, for some strange reason, you allocate `channelsCanvas` as a 3-channel image, and then try to copy single channel images into it -- why?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated the code to be correct. The blue channel of the image is meant to be copied into a region of channelsCanvas. It is not being copied there. When opening up just the region of channelsCanvas the blue channel is meant to copy onto, it appears.

Comment: As I already hinted at, you created `channelsCanvas` with type `CV_8UC3`, but `channelsRGB[0]` is `CV_8UC1` (it's only a single channel, out of the original 3). That means that in `channelsRGB[0].copyTo(BChannel)` the source and destination don't have the same type. As the documentation of [`copyTo`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33fd5d125b4c302b0c9aa86980791a77) states: "If [destination] does not have a proper size or type before the operation, it is reallocated."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dan Mašek gave the correct indication. The canvas I was attempting to put the split channels onto didn't share the same colour type, CV_8UC1. Changing this made it work.
That is to say, I changed the code from
`Mat channelsCanvas = Mat(img.rows*2, img.cols*3, CV_8UC3);` to `Mat channelsCanvas = Mat(img.rows*2, img.cols*3, CV_8UC1);`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).